# How to: Avoid Inserting Related Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have this schema:

http://img602.imageshack.us/img602/6978/schemac.png

I want to insert an Order with OrderItems into database, so I wrote this method:

```
    public void SaveOrder(Order order)
    {
        using (var repository = new StoreEntities())
        {
            // Add order.
            repository.Orders.AddObject(order);

            // Add order items.
            foreach (OrderItem orderItem in order.OrderItems)
            {
                repository.OrderItems.AddObject(orderItem);
            }

            repository.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Everything is inserted just fine, except that **new Product records are inserted too**, which is not what I want.

What I want is to insert Order and its OrderItems, without going any further down the object graph. How can that be achieved?

Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: When you're persisting an OrderItem with a reference to a transient Product, how would it even make sense to *not* persist the product? You'd end up with OrderItems with null as the product reference.

Comment: I already have a database of products, so OrderItem.Product is simply a navigation property to an already persisted product.

Comment: Ah, so what you're saying is that your ProductItems are attached to *non-transient* Products and you're still getting new Products in the database?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So basically after calling the method, I get some duplicate product records in my database. PS - thanks for taking your time to help out :)

Comment: Are you sure your `Orders` and `OrderItems` are connected to existing `Products` the EF way? It's not obvious from your code example.

Comment: @bzlm - what do you mean by the EF way?

Comment: @niaher If EF can determine that the `Product` is not new, it should not be added, and you won't need to `ChangeObjectState` it. So where is your `Product` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call AddObject on the order all items in object graph are marked as inserted. So you have to mark products as unchanged:

```
public void SaveOrder(Order order)     
{         
  using (var repository = new StoreEntities())         
  {             
    // Add order - calling add object marks Order and all entities in its 
    // object graph as Added - they will be inserted to database             
    repository.Orders.AddObject(order);              

    // You don't need to add order items because they should be added together 
    // with order

    // But you don't want to insert Products again, do you?
    // So you have to say that Products are not Added but Unchanged             
    foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)             
    {                 
      // Not sure how to do it with your repository but with ObjectContext 
      // you can do
      // context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(orderItem.Product, 
      //   EntityState.Unchanged);  
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! ChangeObjectState(orderItem.Product, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged) worked like a charm. Thank you. A follow-up question would be - is there a way to cut off an entire line of dependencies. So for example in my case I had to ChangeObjectState of OrderItem.Product and OrderItem.Product.Description to EntityState.Unchanged, but is there a way to specify that with something like StopUpdatePropagation("OrderItem", "Product") with a single call for an entire object context ?

Comment: No there is not any such method. When you work with detached object graph whole object graph is added to ObjectContext and you have to deal with entity states manually.

Comment: just what I needed to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have practically zero EF experience, but it looks like your problem might be that your Products are being saved to a new Context. Would it help if you added this:

```
repository.Attach(orderItem.Product);
```

right before the AddObject call?